# Pointer version of strcat

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, function-definition, strcat

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strpcat(char *s, char *t) {
    int i = 0;
    while (*s++ != '\0')
        i++;
    while ((*(s+i) = *t++) != '\0')
        i++;
}

int main(void) {
    char a[20] = "Hello";
    char b[] = "Bye";
    strpcat(a, b);
    printf("%s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to write rewrite the `strcat()` function with pointers, but when I run the program nothing changes.

Nothing affects to `a` array, what did I do wrong?

Comment: BTW - what do you mean by _"pointer version of strcat"_ ? `strcat` also accepts 2 pointers.

Comment: I have not looked closely but my bet is that you keep the null ending s.

Answer (score 2):

The one problem is this while loop

```
while (*s++ != '\0')
    i++;
```

If `*str` is equal to `'\0'` nevertheless the pointer `s` is incremented. So the original string will not be changed. At least the second string will be appended to the array after the source string.

Another problem is using the variable `i` in the second while loop

```
while ((*(s+i) = *t++) != '\0')
     i++;
```

because the pointer `s` was already incremented in the previous while loop. Using the incremented variable `i` and the incremented pointer `s` the pointer expression `s + i` will have an incorrect address.

The variable `i` is redundant.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
char * strpcat( char *s, const char *t ) 
{
    char *p = s;

    while ( *p ) ++p; 

    while ( ( *p++ = *t++ ) != '\0' );

    return s;
}
```

and called like

```
puts( strpcat( a, b ) );
```

Pay attention to that the second parameter should be declared with the qualifier `const` because the second passed string is not changed within the function. Also you could add the qualifier `restrict` as in the standard function `strcat`

```
char * strpcat( char * restrict s, const char * restrict t );
```

Comment: why did you use *p ? can't we just use *s itself?  if I am asking silly question please forgive me because I don't understand pointers fully yet

Comment: @Dashpoint We need to return a pointer to the string. Within the body of the function the pointer to the string is changed. So  we need to use a copy of the original pointer that will be returned within the body of the function. So the pointer p that is initialized by the original pointer is changed within the function but the original pointer s that points to the first character of the string is returned. Otherwise if to use the original pointer s within the for loops it will point to the terminating zero character of the string and to return it does not make sense

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating it:

```
void strpcat(char* s, char* t) {
  while (*s++ != '\0')
  { // do nothing
  }

  s--;   // need to go back one char so s points to the `\0`.

  while ((*s++ = *t++) != '\0')  // remove the fancy and wrong stuff
  {
     // do nothing
  }
}
```

Comment: or simply `while (*s != '\0') {++s;}` to avoid `s--` call.

Answer (score 1):

2 steps approach:

- Go to the NULL of first string
- Continue to copy second string

```c
void strpcat(char* s, char* t) {
  while (*s != '\0') { ++s; } // Go to the end
  while ((*s++ = *t++) != '\0') {} // Copy source to end of destination
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If applying the [KISS_principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle):

```
#include <string.h>

char* kisscat (char* restrict dst, const char* restrict src)
{
  char* end = dst + strlen(dst);
  strcpy(end, src);
  return dst;
}
```

Now as it happens this is not only more readable, but potentially also faster than rolling any of this out manually. Since these library calls might get inlined into some very efficient code. Unlike a completely hand-made function.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation increments `s` past the null pointer, then copies the string pointed to by `t` well past this position to `s[i]` and so on.  The original null terminator is not overwritten, so `printf("%s\n", a)` still outputs `Hello` and the string in copied too far into the destination array, potentially beyond the end, causing undefined behavior.

If you want to use pointers, do not also use an index and increment only if not pointing to the null pointer already.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *strpcat(char *s, const char *t) {
    while (*s != '\0')
        s++;
    while ((*s = *t++) != '\0')
        s++;
    return s;   // return a pointer to the null terminator.
}

int main(void) {
    char a[20] = "Hello";

    printf("%s\n", a);

    char *p = strpcat(a, " world!");

    printf("%s\n", a);

    strcpy(p, " Bye.");

    printf("%s\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
Hello world!
Hello world! Bye.
```